# Excel : Merging Data sets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to merge two data sets (that each have two columns). Column A is a name, column B is a number in both data sets. Column A of both data sets will have several names that are identical, some will be unique. This is what I am trying to achieve :

[Photo of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axJaN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sort column A in alphaberical order. In another column, use the VLOOKUP function to get values for each name to populate on that column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this, but will result in putting the Names column in alphabetical order. Cells with no data will be blank.

Part 1: List all names, in each Name column.

1. Copy all names from **Data Set B**, and paste them beneath the existing list of names in **Data Set A**.
2. Copy all names from **Data Set A**, and paste them beneath the existing list of names in **Data Set B**.

Part 2: Remove Duplicate Names

3. Select all names (now it is a longer list) in **Data Set A**. In the "Data" tab, select "Data Tools," select "Remove Duplicates".
4. Repeat for names in **Data Set B**

Part 3: Sort data in each set alphabetically by name.

Part 4: Reorganize columns

At this point, both **Name** columns should match up. Simply copy the **2015** column and paste it in desired location adjacent to the **2014** column.

Comment: Part 3 and 4 can be replaced with the VLOOKUP function or INDEX MATCH (same result) to fill in the 2015 column if you don't want alphabetical order.